# Symfony 2 - Forms in base layout

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a project of my own in Symfony -- A simple blog.

I'm having a really hard time trying to develop an article search form like stack overflow does -- a form in the header.

So, the problem is, I'm forced to use an embeded controller in the base template if i want to use symfony's form advantages.

```
<div class="b-header-block m-search">
    {{ render(controller('YagoQuinoySimpleBlogBundle:Blog:searchArticles')) }}
</div>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: You need to explain why you consider this a problem, and what alternative you would prefer, including why you prefer it, and illustrating the problems you had implementing your preferred solution.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Compare with what @gview just commented.

Comment: Mmmm... The first problem came with theming the form. I had to ask it too [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720989/symfony-2-form-theming-overriden-block-renders-two-times), in stackoverflow.

At this point, i'm forced to use and embeded controller and an external form theming template to achieve what i have in mind. So, i thought "let's add the css from the form template", trying to isolate the form and reuse it anywhere. But, from an embeded controller view it's not possible to add assets to stylesheet and javascript blocks.

There is something i'm missing.